# Use xcopy to find and copy file

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

`xcopy` supports `*` wildcards and even allows you to clone whole directory structure. My project uses these Qt libraries I need to distribute:

```
Qt5CLucene.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Help.dll
Qt5Multimedia.dll
Qt5Network.dll
Qt5PrintSupport.dll
Qt5Sql.dll
Qt5Svg.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
Qt5Xml.dll
Qt5XmlPatterns.dll
```

They are not all in the same directory in the Qt installation and the list is subject to change - especially additions. So I wanted to use wildcard `/*/` to find a file anywhere in directory tree:

```
C:\Qt\5.3.0-64> xcopy ".\*\%NAME%.dll" "%~dp0\release"
```

It doesn't work, files are not being found. This is the full code:

```
C:
cd C:\Qt\5.3.0-64\ 

For %%a in (
  "Qt5CLucene"
  "Qt5Core"
  "Qt5Gui"
  "Qt5Help"
  "Qt5Multimedia"
  "Qt5Network"
  "Qt5PrintSupport"
  "Qt5Sql"
  "Qt5Svg"
  "Qt5Widgets"
  "Qt5Xml"
  "Qt5XmlPatterns"
  ) do (
xcopy ".\**\%%~ad.dll" "%~dp0\debug"
)
```

So can I somehow avoid typping full paths (eg. `qtbase\bin\Qt5CLucene`) in the batch?

Comment: Are there also other `*.dll` files that start with `Qt5`, or would `Qt5*.dll` be a suitable search pattern?

Comment: @aschipfl No, it wouldn't. This is what I started with actually, but the extra `.dll` files were annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this (xcopy could ask if you want to create directory - copy is used instead):

```
For /r "C:\Qt\5.3.0-64\" %%a in (
  "*Qt5CLucene.dll"
  "*Qt5Core.dll"
  "*Qt5Gui.dll"
  "*Qt5Help.dll"
  "*Qt5Multimedia.dll"
  "*Qt5Network.dll"
  "*Qt5PrintSupport.dll"
  "*Qt5Sql.dll"
  "*Qt5Svg.dll"
  "*Qt5Widgets.dll"
  "*Qt5Xml.dll"
  "*Qt5XmlPatterns.dll"
) do (
   copy /y "%~fa" "%~dp0\debug"
)
```

Comment: This looks like the best answer, I'm gonna test it. But if someone else used it wit different list of files, wouldn't it also copy files like `blahblahQt5CLucene.dll`?

Comment: @TomášZato Yes but this is limitation of `FOR /R` command - it requires a wildcard..The other and probably better option is `robocopy`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to copy all *.dll files from C:\Qt\5.3.0-64\ -folder and it's sub folders to a debug sub folder of your script file folder.

You could try something like this:

```
:: Start of your *.bat or *.cmd file
FOR /R C:\Qt\5.3.0-64\ %%a IN (*.dll) DO (
   xcopy "%%~a" "%dp~0debug\"
)
:: End of your *.bat or *.cmd file
```

Comment: Nope, I only want those I listed in the question.